# How can I pass dataset attribute to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, attributes

I am trying to get the dataset attributes (data-user-seat-lat and data-user-seat-long) in the option of the Seat selection updated inside of userDetails.
Basically when a user chooses his seat from the dropdown, I want the userSeatLat and userSeatLong to be updated inside of userDetails from data-user-seat-lat and data-user-seat-long. Right now the function formValues is updating the values of Name,Airline and Flight so I've tried adding a function for when the user chooses a seat but without success.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
const Home = () => {
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
        userName: '',
        userAirline: '',
        userFlight: '',
        userSeat:'',
        userSeatLat: '',
        userSeatLong: '',
    });

    
    const formValues = (event) => {
        setUserDetails({
            ...userDetails,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }
    
    const register = async (event) => {

        const body = JSON.stringify({
            userName: userDetails.userName,
            userAirline: userDetails.userAirline,
            userFlight : userDetails.userFlight,
            userSeat : userDetails.userSeat,
            userSeatLat : userDetails.userSeatLat,
            userSeatLong : userDetails.userSeatLong,
        });

        const response = await axios.post("/api/register", body, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="title">Register User</h1>
            <form onSubmit={register}>
                <label>Name: </label>
                <input required type="text" id="userName" name="userName" onChange={formValues}/>
                <br />
                <label>Airline: </label>
                <input required type="text" id="userAirline" name="userAirline" onChange={formValues}/>
                <br />
                    <label>Flight: </label>
                <input required type="text" id="userFlight" name="userFlight" onChange={formValues}/>
                <br />
                <label>Seat: </label>
                <select required type="text" id="userSeat" name = "userSeat" onChange={formValues}>
                    <option id="option1" data-user-seat-lat = "15" data-user-seat-long = "15" >Seat1</option>
                    <option id="option2" data-user-seat-lat = "10" data-user-seat-long = "0" >Seat2</option>
                    <option id="option3" data-user-seat-lat = "-10" data-user-seat-long = "-15" >Seat3</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
                }
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by giving the value property to the options.You do not need to have state variables for lat and long since they're related to seat number. Alternatively you can have a map for each seat value with its respective lat and long value.

```
<select required type="text" id="userSeat" name = "userSeat" onChange={formValues}>
                    <option id="option1" value="1" data-user-seat-lat = "15" data-user-seat-long = "15" >Seat1</option>
                    <option id="option2" value="2" data-user-seat-lat = "10" data-user-seat-long = "0" >Seat2</option>
                    <option id="option3" value="3" data-user-seat-lat = "-10" data-user-seat-long = "-15" >Seat3</option>
</select>
```

and a map like this.

```
const seatMap = {
   "1" : {data-user-seat-lat : "15", data-user-seat-long : "15" },
   "2" : {data-user-seat-lat : "10", data-user-seat-long : "0" },
   "3" : {data-user-seat-lat : "-10", data-user-seat-long : "-15" }
}
```

and just before posting the values set the lat and long according to map like this

```
const body = JSON.stringify({
            userName: userDetails.userName,
            userAirline: userDetails.userAirline,
            userFlight : userDetails.userFlight,
            userSeat : userDetails.userSeat,
            userSeatLat : seatMap[userDetails.userSeat].data-user-seat-lat,
            userSeatLong : seatMap[userDetails.userSeat].data-user-seat-long,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the option that is selected. First get the select element, then use the `selectedIndex` in the `options` collection to get the selected option.

Because you use data attributes you can access the `dataset` property where the values of these attributes can be read. The dash notation `user-seat-lat` is converted into camelCase notation in the dataset: `userSeatLat`.

With a destructuring assignment you access the properties you want from the `dataset` and store them in variables.

Edit: because all the input elements in the form call the `formValues` function you have logic that does not apply to `input` elements. You'll have to do some typechecking to account for the `select` elements.

```
const formValues = (event) => {
    const { target } = event;

    if (target.tagName === 'SELECT') {
        const selectedOption = target.options[target.selectedIndex]
        const { userSeatLat, userSeatLong } = selectedOption.dataset

        setUserDetails({
          ...userDetails,
          userSeatLat,
          userSeatLong,
        })
    } else {
        setUserDetails({
          ...userDetails,
          [target.name]: target.value,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm however getting an error :" TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" at this line : const selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex].

Comment: @martinsenlis. That is because it's a generic function(formValues) with him trying to implement a specific functionality. Not all events have a options prop or a selectedIndex prop(dropdowns have those, input elements don't. You're calling the formValues method from all the onChange handlers). To do it this way you have to have a separate method for only dropdowns.(or have an if else conditon. or you could look up optional chaining)

Comment: @Vikrant is correct. The function was too generic and didn't account for `input` elements. I've included some type checking to see if the element that triggered the function was the `select` element.